# WINAPI IsWindow return false

Tags: winapi

I encounter a case where a window is visible, but `BOOL WINAPI IsWindow(_In_opt_ HWND hWnd);` returns false.
Any ideas?

Comment: Invalid handle?

Comment: Seems implausible. Where is the [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have the correct handle value? Assuming your thread is on the [same desktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681928(v=vs.85).aspx) as the other window it is guaranteed to work correctly. If it returns false then the `HWND` is not valid because A) your `HWND` variable contains a numerical value that is not a valid `HWND`, or B) timing issues where the window is destroyed while you are calling the function.